# How can I avoid loading JavaScript files in partial views?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

In my Symfony project, I have two JavaScript files which are loaded in home page:

```
datetimepicker 
autoComplete
```

When I load the partial view in the home page the JavaScript files are not accessible from the partial view.

How do I avoid loading the same JavaScript files multiple times?

I load my partial views through Ajax

```
//From my partial view 

$(selector).datetimepicker({
  //.....
});

$(selector).autocomplete({
  //.....
});

Error: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
       $(...).autocomplete is not a function
```

Comment: when you say "are not accessible from the partial view" you mean you get an "undefined variable" type error when you try accessing a variable from those files?

Comment: yes I get datetimepicker is not a function.
autoComplete is not a function.

Comment: How do you display your partial pages?

Comment: Can you post your base template code?

Comment: You should try put your JS code, on your base Template, into `{% javascript %}` block, and on page you need to call JS, simply call your JS block, and with `{{ parent() }}` function, and then, your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in your base twig file (base.html.twig  by default), your including your js files before body ending tag

```
        {% block javascripts %}
            <script src=.... />
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

If this is the case the behaviour you're getting is normal, you should either:

- Include your JS files before echoing your body:

{% block body %}{% endblock %}

- The best option would be tu move your JS code from your partial into a separate JS file that you can include after the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

well cant you just do something like

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(data){
        $(selector).datetimepicker({
           //.....
         });

         $(selector).autocomplete({
           //.....
         });
    }
})
```

i also may help you wrap the js-code in the partial views you load into

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

});
```